# Based on a condition perform reranking of elements in the list in python

Tags: python-3.x, loops

i have a ranked list of elements as below :

```
ranked_list_1 = ['G','A','M','S','D']
```

i need to rerank  the list as below

1) Re rank as :

```
re_ranked_list_1 = ['A','M','D','E','G','S']
```

Logic : 'G' and 'S' should always be in last 2 positions and new element 'E' should also be tagged to the list just before the last 2 position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. This will put 'G' and 'S' at the end, in the order they appear in the list.

```
ordered_list = list()
final_terms = ['E']
for item in ranked_list_1:
    if item in ['G', 'S']:
        final_terms.append(item)
    else:
        ordered_list.append(item)

output_list = ordered_list + final_terms

print(output_list)
>>>['A', 'M', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'S']
```